# Cannot add apostrophe to Azure Cloud Service Internal Load Balancer settings

Tags: powershell, azure, internal-load-balancer

How can I add an apostrophe to the **subnet** attribute in the FrontendIPConfiguration for an Azure Cloud Service Internal Load Balancer?

The subnet name contains an apostrophe, this is not an issue when deploying and attaching to a VNet, the apostrophe is allowed in that part of the cscfg configuration and I can publish and see the instances on the VNET.  However, an apostrophe is not allowed in the ILB config section.  This is the config in question:

```
 <LoadBalancers>
      <LoadBalancer name="test-ilb">
        <FrontendIPConfiguration type="private" subnet="VM's" staticVirtualNetworkIPAddress="10.120.16.102" />
      </LoadBalancer>
    </LoadBalancers>
```

In Visual Studio I cannot publish the cloud service due to this.  I have also tried creating a package and editing the cscfg config outside of VS and then uploading.  I have tried using powershell to add the ILB after I have uploaded it, but recieved an error saying the operation cannot be performed on a deployment containing  web or worker roles.

Finally, I have tried substituting the apostrophe with a different value (some of these are long shots), but none worked:

```
&#39;
&#0039;
&apos;
''
\'
&#x27;
&#x0027;
```

Any help would be appreciated.  The alternative of renaming the subnet would be a longer path to take and I am hoping to avoid it.

Comment: Have you tried setting this through powershell directly? Something like: `Add-AzureInternalLoadBalancer -InternalLoadBalancerName MyILB -SubnetName VM's -ServiceName MyWebsite1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Special characters are not supported
Yves